# How to start using Beaker in Django

Tags: python, django, beaker

Question: Could people show or point me toward a complete example or tutorial to start using Beaker in Django?

Information: 
Since I've read about problems in database connection with django ORM [here](http://adam.gomaa.us/blog/2007/aug/26/the-django-orm-problem/) I've decided to replace Django's ORM with sqlalchemy, but that means I can't use sessions from Django.

Beaker looks promising to me, but I don't know where to start. The Beaker documentation left me with many questions such as:

- What is WSGIAPP?
- How do I use a Beaker session in my Django view?
- Where is a runnable example?

Could people show or point me toward a complete example or tutorial to start using Beaker in Django?

Note: I'm using Django-1.1.1 and Beaker 1.5

Comment: Can you reference the "problem in database connection with django orm" with a link?

Comment: Oops! miss link

The correct link is http://adam.gomaa.us/blog/2007/aug/26/the-django-orm-problem/

Comment: You know that you can use Django's sessions without a database by using the in-memory version, or memcached?  Take a look:  http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#session-engine

Comment: Yes I knowed and decided to move on using django session with file store.

My supervisor think file is good enough but I still doubt how to integrate Beaker with Django.

Comment: The article you referenced is more than two years old and was written before Django 1.0. The code referenced in the article doesn't exist anymore. Before you make yourself more problems than necessary, go one step back and reconsider going away from Django ORM, since your decision apparently generated more questions rather than solved your problems. To give you better advice, tell us what your project is all about?

Comment: I'm building a web site that have these key features. 
1. video on demand (another youtube).
2. live broadcast (live tv on internet)

I've team who could solve problem for project direction. (I said i'm decided but in fact is the team's decision.)

I'm just want to know how to integrate Beaker to Django.

Anyway thank for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

This question is old so I'm not sure if this is still needed, but here is one link: http://seeknuance.com/2010/09/16/multiple-cache-backends-in-django/